# OpenCv bitwise Operations physical meaning

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have started with OpenCv pretty recently and the online documentation seems to be pretty good. However there is this one tutorial about image addition and "bitwise operations". I am very badly stuck at the following point

```
 `# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
  img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

  # Take only region of logo from logo image.
  img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)`
```

I read about bit wise operations and I understood what they are. But I have not been able to find in really simple language what the above 2 lines are doing? What is the argument mask in the above functions doing?

I am following the following tutorial

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html

If anybody can explain me in really simple language what is happening in these  lines of code or if anyone can point me to a good source that explains it from the very basic, I shall be really grateful.

Regards

Nischal

Answer (score 0):

The code will create an image with all original pixels of `img2` that are in the foreground mask and an image with all original pixels of image `roi` that are in the background mask (inverted foreground mask).

So the result is an image, where all non-mask pixel become black and the rest is unchanged.

First it computes the bitwise AND of the image, which will just be the image itself (exactly each bit that is 1 will be 1 afterwards). But in addition it applies the mask and leaves every pixel 0 that is not active in the mask.

Imho this is a bit hacked and the code should be instead:

```
# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,mask_inv)

# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,mask)
```

but for this to work, the mask must have the same number of channels as the image, so this will often not work and will introduce some overhead by converting the mask to multi-channel image.

Comment: HI Micka, would it be correct to say that it calculates intersection of 2 images?

Comment: only if both images (or at least one image) are masks. Otherwise it is unclear what "intersection" should mean. Maybe it really is some kind of intersection in the RGB space, for example, if one pixel in the first image is pure red and the pixel in the second image is pure blue, the bitwise-and will be black, because they dont't "overlap" in the RGB range. But what if first pixel is (128,128,128) and the second pixel is (127,127,127)? the result will be again 0, since we have bytes 10000000 and 01111111 here. So I think in general, "intersection" isnt the right word.

Comment: What kind of problems/tasks are typically performed with bitwise operations can be seen here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score -1):

Create filter to remove the color logo from the original image

```
# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
 img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
```

extract only the logo from the original image

```
# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)`
```

Add them up to just extract the logo(color)

To get an in depth information you can use

```
help(function)
```

inside python console

```
>>> help(cv2.bitwise_and)
Help on built-in function bitwise_and:
```

This is what the out you get hope it helps you understand what exactly is happening

```
Help on built-in function bitwise_and:

bitwise_and(...)
bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) -> dst
.   @brief computes bitwise conjunction of the two arrays (dst = src1 & src2)
.   Calculates the per-element bit-wise conjunction of two arrays or an
.   array and a scalar.
.   
.   The function cv::bitwise_and calculates the per-element bit-wise logical conjunction for:
.   *   Two arrays when src1 and src2 have the same size:
.   \f[\texttt{dst} (I) =  \texttt{src1} (I)  \wedge \texttt{src2} (I) \quad \texttt{if mask} (I) \ne0\f]
.   *   An array and a scalar when src2 is constructed from Scalar or has
.   the same number of elements as `src1.channels()`:
.   \f[\texttt{dst} (I) =  \texttt{src1} (I)  \wedge \texttt{src2} \quad \texttt{if mask} (I) \ne0\f]
.   *   A scalar and an array when src1 is constructed from Scalar or has
.   the same number of elements as `src2.channels()`:
.   \f[\texttt{dst} (I) =  \texttt{src1}  \wedge \texttt{src2} (I) \quad \texttt{if mask} (I) \ne0\f]
.   In case of floating-point arrays, their machine-specific bit
.   representations (usually IEEE754-compliant) are used for the operation.
.   In case of multi-channel arrays, each channel is processed
.   independently. In the second and third cases above, the scalar is first
.   converted to the array type.
.   @param src1 first input array or a scalar.
.   @param src2 second input array or a scalar.
.   @param dst output array that has the same size and type as the input
.   arrays.
.   @param mask optional operation mask, 8-bit single channel array, that
.   specifies elements of the output array to be changed.
```